# Do not understand this code

Tags: f#, recursion, pattern-matching, tail-recursion

I am new to F# and found some code that I would like to use.  This code takes a list and returns the second half of the list.  I am hoping someone can go over line by line of what it does.  I want to change it so it returns the first half of the list. Here is the code after it is my questions.

```
let cut l = 
   let rec cut = function
       | xs, ([] | [_]) -> xs  
       | [], _ -> []
       | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> cut (xs, ys)
   cut (l, l)
```

What does `= function` do?

I am pretty sure that `| xs, ([] | [_]) -> xs` is if there is `xs` add it to the list

I do not understand what this does `| [], _ -> []`

`| x::xs, y::y'::ys -> cut (xs, ys)`: I understand the first half, it creates two sublists, what confuses me is why cut is sending the tail `xs`, and `ys`.  Doesn't cut only take one parameter?

Comment: Just to clarify - is this a question for a homework? If yes, we're still happy to help & give you some pointers, but not a complete solution (that you can start selling :-)).

Comment: It is part of an assignment, As I mentioned I am trying to figure out how it works so I can manipulate it.  For some reason when I use the debugger it does not  go into the function.  So I am puzzled about this

Comment: The debugger may work better if you use the `match` syntax (and you can also more easily add `printf` to print some debugging info).

Comment: @Tomas I changed it to match and for some reason the debugger does not work on this function, it works fine on others

Answer (score 5):

The function returns the second half of the given list.

The interesting part of the code is only the nested (recursive) function, because the only purpose of the outer function is to call the nested function and pass it the specified list two times. The nested `cut` function has two arguments (as a tuple), so it's type is:

```
cut : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list
```

When calling itself recursively, this is the function that is called (which explains why it is called with two arguments). Here is the commented code:

```
// The 'function' syntax means that the arguments of the function are matched against 
// several clauses. When the arguments (lists) match the clause, the clause is selected
// and its body will be executed. 
let rec cut = function
  // When the second list is empty or contains a single element,
  // the function return all elements of the first list
  | xs, ([] | [_]) -> xs  
  // When the first list is empty, return empty list
  | [], _ -> []
  // When first list is non-empty and second contains at least two elements,
  // the function takes one element from the first list and two elements from 
  // the second list (x, y, y'), ignores them and calls itself with the 
  // remaining lists as arguments.
  | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> cut (xs, ys)

cut ([ 1 .. 10 ], [ 1 .. 10 ])
```

The idea of the function is that it iterates over two copies of the same list. At every recursive step, it skips two elements from the second one and one element from the first one. By the time it reaches the end of the second list, the first one contains the second half of the list (because the function was skipping its elements 2-times slower).

**To get the first half of the list** you'll need to add additional parameter to your inner recursive `cut` function. You can use it for accumulating the elements from the first list. Again, you'll need to skip over elements of one of the list two-times faster. Instead of skipping first elements of the other list, you'll need to take them and add them to your accumulator.

I will not give you a full solution, but to give you some idea, here is pseudo-code:

```
  | x::xs, _::_::ys -> 
      // Call 'cut' recursively to process 'xs' and 'ys'
      // and add the element 'x' to the accumulator.
```

**Another way** to write the function would be to use `match` instead of `function` and write the two arguments as standard multiple arguments (instead of using a tuple). When ignoring elements in the last clause, it is also possible to use `_` because their names are not needed:

```
let rec cut l1 l2 = 
  match l1, l2 with
  | xs, ([] | [_]) -> xs  
  | [], _ -> []
  | _::xs, _::_::ys -> cut xs ys

cut [ 1 .. 10 ] [ 1 .. 10 ]
```

Comment: Took me a while but I finally figured out why you get the second half of the list

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change it to return the first half of the list is: pass the reversed list into the inner function and reverse the result.

```
let cut l = 
  let rec cut = function
    | xs, ([] | [_]) -> xs  
    | [], _ -> []
    | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> cut (xs, ys)
  let k = List.rev l
  cut (k, k) |> List.rev
```

#### Without List.rev

```
let cut l = 
  let rec cut f = function
    | x::_, [_] -> f [x]
    | _, [] -> f []
    | [], _ -> []
    | x::xs, _::_::ys -> cut (fun acc -> f (x::acc)) (xs, ys)
  cut id (l, l)
```

Comment: How would you go about it without using List.rev?

Comment: @Aaron: Just read the comments in your original post. I kinda figured it was homework, but hey, by the time you can explain this solution, you will have earned it. It should get you thinking in a new direction.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to see what the cut function is doing is by realizing that the line below

```
| x::xs, y::y'::ys -> cut (xs, ys)
```

is emptying the 2nd list twice as fast as the 1st list. This is because it's pulling 2 elements off the head of the `ys` list and one element off the head of the `xs` list and throwing them away. If it does this continuously then `ys` will terminate first and when it does `xs` will contain the lower half of the original list.